# Elasticsearch index as a source to apache flink batch job

Tags: apache-flink

I am fairly new to Apache Flink. I have a specific requirement were I have to use elasticsearch index as a source. I tried to figure out if flink has a source as elasticsearch but doesn't seem to be. I could see that we can have elasticsearch as a sink but direct support as a source is not there. Can anyone guide me on how we can solve this problem. I am using elasticsearch 5.5.0 and flink 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I, found one flink elasticsearcg source connector implementation on git - https://github.com/mnubo/flink-elasticsearch-source-connector. But it seems that it has not been active for almost a year now and has limited support in terms on aggregation and es version.

Thought of sharing this just in case if it meets someone's requirement.